# Angular JS + Rest API + SharePoint List - two way binding is not working

Tags: angularjs

I am using sharepoint application to do CRUD in sharepoint list. View and New Item Add operation are working fine. but i am stuck with Update operation. although i used a controller for Edit , and getting employee data based on ID . but data is not showing at html page.

Please Help.

Comment: Could you please put your code to JSFiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Jfw9R/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done. i was doing a mistake and not having "  async: false," in my header request.

Answer (score 0):

Updated - http://jsfiddle.net/Jfw9R/1/
First of all included AngularJS lib, second thing - **ng-app**  - it's quite important:

```
<body ng-app="employeesApp">
```

Now could you specify your problem, please? because it's quite big amount of code

Comment: HTML i provided is edit.html which serve as view and is referred in to main html page list.html. now list.html page is again server as view in application.aspx page. let me try to update my code in JSFiddle.

Comment: sorry, it will not work. you should specify the exact problem. Do you know how debug JavaScript?

Comment: i created a separate question for this. might be description there will be helpful. i know how to debug js. also there is no error coming .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21473282/angular-js-rest-api-sharepoint-list-validation-and-edit-not-working