# Angular Js + Rest API + Sharepoint List - Validation and Edit not working

Tags: angularjs

I am having 2 problems in below code.

```
    // http://jsfiddle.net/Jfw9R/7/
```

1. Validation is not working when i try to run the application as main page - applicationpage.aspx page.  but when i use any html page for main page validation is working fine.
2. when i click on edit at list.html page. it is redirecting me to edit.html page. that is ok. but data is not coming for the employee for whom i want to edit. data only coming when i change some text in any input control. i don't why ?

Thanks

Comment: #2 point is done. i was doing a mistake in header and was not providing "async: false,". now it is working fine. but i don't know why it was not displaying data when it is "  async: true," . can some one help me out here ?

Comment: can we apply angular js validation with out form tag ?

Comment: #1 now this is done as i have to provide there ng-form tag instead of form in child page. which is edit.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 1 now this is done as i have to provide there ng-form tag instead of form in child page. which is edit.html –